# Java - Batch Insertion Process

Tags: java, sql, database, backend

I've been wondering these past few days on how Java's Batch Insert works on back-end. Here's a sample code that I've been look to give myself an idea:

```
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < myArrayList.size(); ctr = ctr ++ ) {

    myStatement.setObject(1, myArrayList.get(ctr) );
    myStatement.addBatch();
    myStatement.clearParameters();

}
```

Then call `myStatement.executeBatch()` afterwards. This sample code left me 2 ideas.

First, after calling `executeBatch()`, does the database execute `INSERT` statement per `myStatement` batch? If `myStatement` batch size is 3, then will the database execute `INSERT` statement 3 times?
If yes, then will the database execute the `INSERT` statement from the first batch to bottom or the opposite? (Yes, the arrangement of batch matters to me)
Second, does the database execute a single `INSERT` statement with the VALUES separated in comma?

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly driver dependendent how everything is encoded to the server, but the general gist is that it stores up the requested statement executions (along with the parameters for each execution), and when you call "executeBatch" it sends them all to the server at once.  The execution order is guaranteed to be in the order you call "addBatch" in your code.  So you code in the order you want it executed (not reverse order as you thought might be an option).

Because it's one call to the server, it's generally faster to do it this way, since you don't have to make lots of round trips.  That's the main advantage to doing this.

Batch sizing is kind of an artform, but if you look at something like hibernate (that can use batching under the hood if you ask it to), they recommend somewhere around 15 executions per batch.  Take that with a grain of salt, but that's a good starting number.